# Functions stops working when being included from another file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to do a quick experiment on if I was able to do my own simple video player. Heres my HTML so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
  <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
  <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
  <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
  <br><br>
  <video id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_30mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div> 

<script>
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1"); 

function playPause() { 
  if (myVideo.paused) 
    myVideo.play(); 
  else 
    myVideo.pause(); 
} 

function makeBig() { 
    myVideo.width = 560; 
} 

function makeSmall() { 
    myVideo.width = 320; 
} 

function makeNormal() { 
    myVideo.width = 420; 
} 

</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

As you can see, it works flawlessly. Tho, if I add my script in a new file, heres the result....

```js
alert("file included."); // check if file has been included correctly

var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1"); 

function playPause() { 
  if (myVideo.paused) 
    myVideo.play(); 
  else 
    myVideo.pause(); 
} 

function makeBig() { 
    myVideo.width = 560; 
} 

function makeSmall() { 
    myVideo.width = 320; 
} 

function makeNormal() { 
    myVideo.width = 420; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
  <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
  <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
  <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
  <br><br>
  <video id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_30mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div> 


</body> 
</html>
```

Okay, so here it will still work for some reason, but if you copy the code over into an "index.html" and a "main.js" youll get the following error:

```html
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'paused' of null
    at playPause (main.js:6)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):10)
```

That error doesnt occurs when the javascript code is include within the html.
Why is that? Im using chromium.

Thanks!

Comment: Because the element doesn't exist in that file.

Comment: @JackBashford Thanks for the quick reply! Tho, I cant really add the element in the javascript file? Ive never encountered that problem before... Normally, when using "getElementById", it just works. Why not here?

Comment: either wait for the element to exist, or load the script at the end of the body tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with id `video1` is not accessible as the DOM has not been loaded completely. Consider moving the `script` element to the bottom of the `body` or using the event [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

Comment: Thanks alot, solved my problem! Theres still something I dont understand tho... Lets say the page finishes loading. Why isnt javascript still not able to detect new elements?

Comment: If the file is loaded, javascript will be able to detect the elements. The problem is you're assigning the element to a property before the element exists in `var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1"); ` then using that property for your actions. If you moved that line inside of the methods, it would then be able to find the element because the actions occur after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Move the script to the end of body. You're trying to get the element before it exists.

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");
```

```
...
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an onload listener to your JS file:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // All your code
};
```

Alternatively, move the `<script>` tag to the end of your file, just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
  <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the video if you are including the functions from a different file.

`myVideo.load()` should do the fix.